# Diagnosing error in setting environment variable (Ubuntu based server, Django app)

Tags: ubuntu, django, environment-variables

In `.profile` found at `/home/myuser/`, I set an environment variable as follows: `export API_TOKEN=xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyyxxxxxyyyyyxx`, and then running `source ~/.profile`.

This server has a Django app on it; where I import the env variable in `settings.py` (via `API_TOKEN = os.environ.get('API_TOKEN','1')`) and then use it to call an analytics API I'm using for my app.

The problem is that Django is unable to import the token at all.

When I do `env` in the terminal, I **do see** `API_TOKEN=xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyyyxxxxxyyyyyxx` among the list of environment variables printed. What could be going wrong, and how can I diagnose the problem?

---

Note that I do not see the token printed if I do `env` in *super user*. Could that be an issue? But there are several other env variables I'm using in this way, and those import correctly even though they don't appear for super user.

Comment: "run a Django app" ... how? Webservices typically do not poke around in user dot files, especially if they are started by the init system.

Comment: @thrig: I got the point, you mean I should interface it via the web application server. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I passed the environment variable values separately through my application webserver conf, only then was my app able to import the value correctly.